# $reverse_top_level works the opposite way according to Codex?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, codex

The Codex for [wp_list_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) states `$reverse_top_level
    (boolean) (optional) Setting this to true will display the most recent comment first then going back in order.`

For my it is actually the opposite way. `false` option will display the latest comment as the first one and `true` option or if the option is not used at all will the last one. The same applies if comment pagination is used or is not used.

Similar behavior applies to `reverse_children` option. If `false` or not used at all the latest child is the first one.

Code used along with WordPress 3.6.1 on TurnKey

```
    $comments =     get_comments(array(
        'number' => $get_comments_number_approved,
//          'offset' => 10,
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'status' => 'approve' ,
        'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ));

        wp_list_comments(array(
            'reverse_top_level' => false, //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
            'reverse_children' => false,
            'page' => $page_number,
            'per_page' => $comments_per_page,
//              'avatar_size'   => 16,
        ), $comments);
```

Did I miss something or is it a bug or Codex needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

The default for `reverse_top_level` is `null`. Now let's take a look at [the function source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1571):

```
if ( null === $r['reverse_top_level'] )
    $r['reverse_top_level'] = ( 'desc' == get_option('comment_order') );
```

As you can see, it takes the value from the `comment_order` option. And that is either `desc` or `asc`. If the value is `desc`, then it will be set to `true`. Now [`Walker_Comment`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1217), which [`extends Walker`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/190913aaa79f96e014f7ba27bb442e4b522087f1/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L14), retrieves the parsed arguments `$r` as last argument for `paged_walk()`. And that method is a method of the `Walker` class. Let's look at its [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/190913aaa79f96e014f7ba27bb442e4b522087f1/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L270). And [there we can see](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/190913aaa79f96e014f7ba27bb442e4b522087f1/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L341) the following:

```
if ( ! empty( $args[0]['reverse_top_level'] ) )
    $elements = array_reverse( $elements );
    // does other stuff here
```

As `empty` evaluates `false` equal to `null` or `! isset`, this part won't trigger. That's it.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand. My point is that Codex explains that the value `true` gives us the most recent comment first. I am getting the oldest first if I use the value true. The null part is just that I would expect the most recent to be displayed too. But my question is more about the true giving me the oldest comments first.

Comment: Radek, have you checked the "comment order" in your admin UI settings?

Comment: I thought the custom code got higher priority ...

Comment: @Radek There is no priority, because the "custom code" doesn't get executed/used. Please read my explanation again - carefully. Then you'll see why your argument gets ignored by core.